# ppl011 fails to install on 10.9.2

Tags: rvm, homebrew

I'm trying to install **ppl011** using brew and it fails.

The story began when I did **rvm requirements**. It failed during the gcc46 step. When I tried to install gcc46 itself, it failed while installing ppl011. Eventually, I was able to generate these: https://gist.github.com/ege02/9490126

I have been googling this for the past 24 hours. I'm also new to OSX/Linux so I pretty much have no idea what I'm doing. I'd appreciate some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

I'll add this in case it helps someone. It turned out that the issue was caused by an incompatibility with the (as of this writing) recently released Command Line Tools 5.1. Downgrading to CLT 5.0.1 allowed me to work around the issue. More details [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/27431#issuecomment-37322474).